# Problem with XMLHttpRequest conditional XMLHttp.status==200

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, status, readystate

My Ajax works just fine until I add a conditional status property.
Here's the snippet

```
if (XMLHttp.readyState==4 && XMLHttp.status==200){
    // do something
}
```

and here's the complete code

```
function getXMLHttp()
            {
             try
             {
              var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
              // document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML="<h1>Using XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>";
              //alert('Mozilla XMLHttpRequest Obeject Created Successfully');
             }
             catch(err1)
             {
              var ieXmlHttpVersions = new Array();
              ieXmlHttpVersions[ieXmlHttpVersions.length] = "MSXML2.XMLHttp.7.0";
              ieXmlHttpVersions[ieXmlHttpVersions.length] = "MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0";
              ieXmlHttpVersions[ieXmlHttpVersions.length] = "MSXML2.XMLHttp.5.0";
              ieXmlHttpVersions[ieXmlHttpVersions.length] = "MSXML2.XMLHttp.4.0";
              ieXmlHttpVersions[ieXmlHttpVersions.length] = "MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0";
              ieXmlHttpVersions[ieXmlHttpVersions.length] = "MSXML2.XMLHttp";
              ieXmlHttpVersions[ieXmlHttpVersions.length] = "Microsoft.XMLHttp";

              var i;
              for (i=0; i < ieXmlHttpVersions.length; i++)
              {
               try
               {
                var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(ieXmlHttpVersions[i]);
                // var catatan = "<h1>Using " + ieXmlHttpVersions[i] + "</h1>";
                break;
               }
               catch (err2)
               {
                var xmlhttp = null;
                //alert(ieXmlHttpVersions[i] + " not supported.");
               }
              }
             }

             if (typeof xmlhttp == "undefined" || xmlhttp == null){
              //document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML="<h1>XMLHttp cannot be created!</h1>";
              alert('XMLHttp Request Object Is not Supported Somehow');
              }
              return xmlhttp;
            }
            var XMLHttp = getXMLHttp();


            function loadData(url, targetID){
                if(!url) {var url="data.txt";}
                if(!targetID){var targetID='ajaxID';}
                XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function (){getResponse(targetID)};
                XMLHttp.open('GET', url, true);
                XMLHttp.send(null);
            }
            function getResponse(targetID){
                var data = XMLHttp.responseText;
                var ajaxContent=document.getElementById('ajax_content');

                if(XMLHttp.readyState == 4){ 
                // This works Just fine, data from data.txt actually fetched
                // BUT When i Add this if statement with " && XMLHttp.status==200" It's not returning data from data.txt
                    if(data.length > 0){
                        fill(targetID,data);
                    }
                }
            }

            function fill(ID,data){
                hideLoading();
                document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = data;
            }
            function showLoading(){
                document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility='';
                document.getElementById('loading_text').innerHTML = '....Loading Please Wait....';
            }
            function hideLoading(){
                document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('loading_text').innerHTML = '';
            }
```

My question is why I can't get the data from `data.txt` when I add `&& XMLHttp.status==200` statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Could your web-server be returning one of the other 'success' status codes from the [HTTP specification?](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Try testing if `(XMLHttp.status >= 200 && XMLHttp.status < 300)`.

Can you tell us whether you know or don't know if execution-flow is getting to the `fill(targetID,data)` line? It would be very unusual if the `XMLHttp.status` check were interfering in the actual data retrieval step.

From what you've told us, it seems that `XMLHttp.readyState` must be reaching `4` without `XMLHttp.status == 200`. Have I misinterpreted your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think its the problem in creating the XMLHTTP object. try use the basic syntax that has been provided by w3schools.

```
            var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
    }
```

its work for me or use jquery or prototype.